# Expected an assignment or function call error in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is actually a component that I'm trying to implement in ReactJS

Here is the code snippet:

```
const Leaders=({leaders, isLoading, errMess})=>{
    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <Loading />
        )
    }
    else if (errMess) {
        return (
            <h4>{errMess}</h4>
        )
    }
    else {
        return (
            leaders.map((leader) => {
                <Stagger in>
                    <Fade in>
                        <Media>
                            <Media object left src={baseUrl + leader.image} alt={leader.name} className='my-image mt-5'></Media>
                            <Media body className="ml-5 mt-0">
                                <Media heading>
                                    {leader.name}
                                </Media>
                                <p className='font-card'>{leader.designation}</p>
                                <p>{leader.description}</p>
                                <hr></hr>
                            </Media>
                        </Media>
                    </Fade>
                </Stagger>})
        )
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an error: `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression` at the return part of the else condition.

A solution to resolve this issue is much appreciated

Comment: the code seems fine, however this className='my-image mt-5' here, you should use double quotes (")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your map function doesn't return anything at the end, so you have to add return to your jsx:

```js
leaders.map((leader) => { return <Stagger in> ... // should add return
```

Comment: That solved the issue, but isn't the else condition returned as an whole? Why do I need another return inside the map function?

Comment: Since `Array.prototye.map` is to create a new array by loop each item and return the new one so your purpose to create the JSX for each item. If you don't return anything, it will create the list with each item is void 0 :)

Answer (score 1):

When you have a curly brace for an arrow function:

```
(leader) => {
  // ...
}
```

...then each item in between braces is a *statement*. You have an *expression statement* which doesn't do anything:

```
<Stagger in>...</Stagger>
```

What you want is a *return* statement which will become the result of the function. Otherwise, the function implicitly returns `undefined`, and React spits out an error if you try to render an `undefined` value:

```
return <Stagger in>...<Stagger>
```

...or change your arrow function to not use curly braces so you can have an *expression* as the body, creating an implicit return statement:

```
(leader) => (
  <Stagger in>
    ...
  </Stagger>
)
```